# Autifil column based on another column data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set which is shown in the image below.
I have also shown what result i would like to get in the image.

To explain, i want the autofil to only fill the cells based on the adjacent column (column I/S) cells. There could be blanks in between the rows and it should skip that and continue till the last row.

i have the formula to autofil all the way down to the last row and even for the one which works similar to the manual double click to autofil.

Would appreciate any help to be able to get this working.

The code i am using for autofil is below. The result is in the image too.

```
Dim Name As String
For Each C In Range("H2:H" & Cells(rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cells(C.Row, 1) > "" Then
        Name = Cells(C.Row, 1)
    Else
        Cells(C.Row, 1).Value = Name
    End If
Next
```

Also for some reason this code always autofils column A. How can i reference it to the column i need to perform the autofil?

[Data and Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzrfk.png)

Note: The values can be anything (1 and 4 are just for reference)

Thanks!

Comment: Q: Im not following why you are testing if something is greater than (>) blank in this `If Cells(C.Row, 1) > "" Then`.  Is this supposed to test if the cell has a value?  If so then you will need to change it to `If Cells(C.Row, 1) <> "" Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Else
    Cells(C.Row, 1).Value = Name
```

assigns the value of the cell in Column A because of the `,1`.  Change the 1 to the numerical value of the column you wish the data to populate to.

Example:  If you wanted the data to populate in Column C you would use:

```
Else
    Cells(C.Row, 3).Value = Name
```

Comment: Hi Zack,
Thanks for the brilliant thought. I did it as you suggested and changed the column numbers as needed and it does do the work i intended it to do.
however just to note that it also autofills blank rows. This i can work with.

Comment: I would also change `If Cells(C.Row, 1) > "" Then` to `If Cells(C.Row, 1) <> "" `Please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Hi Zack, apologies. Yes i did change that too. Your logic made sense.